# Change Between 2 Stylesheets Dynamically Flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, air

I have a Flex mobile project with two different style sheets:

- theme1.css (Contains all the css for theme 1)
- theme2.css (Contains all the css for theme 2)

The project needs to import only ONE stylesheet at a time.

How can I create a button that switches between two stylesheets and refreshes the screen?

Thanks
Phil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    switch (this.themeSelected) { 
                case 0: 
                    this.styleManager.loadStyleDeclarations("../light.swf", true);
                    break ; 
                case 1: 
                    this.styleManager.loadStyleDeclarations("../alt.swf", true);
                    break ; 
                case 2: 
                    this.styleManager.loadStyleDeclarations("../dark.swf", true);
                    break ; 
                case 3: 
                    this.styleManager.loadStyleDeclarations("../impaired.swf", true);
                    break ; 

    }
```

You need to compile your css to swf, by rightclicking on the file in Flash Builder Burrito and checking the compile to SWF options